# How to base fluid text sizing formula on rem value?

Tags: css, fluid-layout

I've been exploring fluid font sizing and found many examples online. Basically it looks like they all come down to a linear interpolation formula like this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_interpolation.

T = T₁ + ((V - V₁) / (V₂ - V₁)) * (T₂ - T₁)

Where:
T = output fluid text font size
T₁ = minimum fluid text font size
T₂ = maximum fluid text font size
V = 100vw (current viewport width)
V₁ = minimum viewport width
V₂ = maximum viewport width

This works great for pixels and I've implemented it with this calc():

```
calc(${t_1}px + ((100vw - ${v_1}px) / (${v_2} - ${v_1})) * (${t_2} - ${t_1}));
```

Note: *values are populated dynamically and the CSS output generated in PHP but I don't think that makes any difference to this question.*

Now I'm hoping to use this same formula but basing it on the current browser root font size.

```
calc(${t_1}rem + ((100vw - ${v_1}px) / (${v_2} - ${v_1})) * ((${t_2} - ${t_1}) * 1rem));
```

Using the same CSS calc() as the first example and swapping in rem for px values would work except that I run into issues where I'm trying to multiply px * rem units which isn't possible. If I could strip units from the rem value here ...`((${t_2} - ${t_1}) * 1rem))` it would fix my issue but this doesn't seem possible in CSS? No matter how I rearrange the formula, I'm introducing one unit with the 100vw value, and another unit with the rem value.

My current ugly workaround is to use javascript to get the current root font size and place this value into a CSS variable after stripping its unit.

```
var rootFontSize = window.getComputedStyle(document.documentElement, null).getPropertyValue('font-size');
var rootFontVal = parseFloat(rootFontSize);
document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--rem-val', rootFontVal);
```

Then use this CSS variable in my formula like this:

```
calc(${t_1}rem + ((100vw - ${v_1}px) / (${v_2} - ${v_1})) * ((${t_2} - ${t_1}) * var(--rem-val)));
```

This works as expected and the fluid text size is now based on the browser root font size. But.. I'd really like to get rid of the javascript. Is there any other way to strip units or get the raw value of 1rem in CSS? Or a way to rearrange the formula to eliminate the need to multiply the units?

Comment: why do you need `* var(--rem-val)`? can't you move around some values to only multiply unitless values with `* 1rem`?

Comment: I've tried every way that I can think of. I'm sure I could be missing something though and I'd be glad to try again if you have an idea of how I could?

Comment: can you remove the php vars and replace them with actual runtime values?

Comment: I'm applying the result of the CSS calc() to a CSS variable. Here is the actual printout from viewing the page source:

--rem-val: 16;
--title-size-1: calc(2rem + ((100vw - 480px) / (1120 - 480)) * ((4 - 2) * var(--rem-val)));